# Obtain a String in Json format from a Vertex instance

Tags: java, json, orientdb, vertex

In a Java application with an OrientDB database, after I have a Vertex object, I need to extract its properties in a String object. This object must be in Json format.
An example of expected result is:

```
 {"@type":"d","@rid":"#13:1093","@version":1,"@class":"V_Notification","lastUpdateDate":"2016-07-20 16:45:31","lastUpdateUser":"#12:41","creationDate":"2016-07-20 16:45:31","creationUser":"#12:41","type":"user_added_to_share_made_upload","description":"user_added_to_share_made_upload","sphereId":"#16:18","out_E_NotificationUser":["#45:1091"],"deleted":false,"version":0,"isRead":false,"@fieldTypes":"lastUpdateDate=t,lastUpdateUser=x,creationDate=t,creationUser=x,out_E_NotificationUser=g"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
OrientVertex v=g.getVertex("#9:0");
ODocument d=v.getRecord();
String json=d.toJSON();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can try [gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) and than use something like:

`Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonInString = gson.toJson(yourOrientObj);`

Ref.: [mkyong.com](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Comment: Works, but I have a problems with encoding characters. For example, instead of ', I have  \u0027.

Answer (score 1):

I made an example to try your case:

`@class:` V_Notification

`Property:` description

```
Vertex v = graph.getVertex("#17:0");
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonInString = gson.toJson(v.getProperty("description").toString());
System.out.println("STAMPO = " + jsonInString);
```

This is my output:

```
PRINTED = "user_added_to_share_made_upload"
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.